# How to sniff Flatbuffers in Python?

Tags: python, flatbuffers

Once reading in memory a binary, is there an efficient way to tell whether the binary is a Flatbuf? Preferably a Python solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is provision of 4 byte "root identifier" at beginning of buffer(search for it in flat buffer schema language). If your schema has implemented that, you can just validate first 4 bytes.

Or if you have the generated interfaces with you, you may run the complete "flatbuffer verifier" on binary to see if it's a valid flat buffer.

Comment: You can use the `file_identifier` to tell if a binary is likely a particular type of FlatBuffer (when you find it at offsets 4 to 8 in the binary), but there is no way to tell if it is any type of FlatBuffer. Other kinds of binaries may have text at that location.
Also, the verifier will only tell for a particular kind of FlatBuffer if it is safe to access, not if it corresponds to the schema. So there are binaries that will pass the verifier (containing e.g. mostly zeros) but represent an empty table for a given schema.